# PHP json_decode characters issue

Tags: php, curl

I'v a json return from a URL web service, using cURL, if I print it, normal characters are shown, but, when I fwrite it in a CVC file and open it using Excel, the characters change. EX: Ribeirão Preto, turns "RibeirÃ£o Preto".

Return of service:

```html
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

I'v tried utf8_decode (encode), header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Can Help?

block of code:

```
foreach ($list as $key) {

$cep = trim($key["cep"]);

$link = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/json/";

$ch = curl_init($link);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

if ($data !== true) {
    $data["cep"] = "CEP Ínvalido";
}else
{
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
}

array_push($ceps, $data);
curl_close($ch);
```

}

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW');
$fileName = $date->format ('Y-m-d\TH-i-s');
echo $list->writeFile($fileName, $ceps, "AGF");
```

To write the file, I use like:

```html
$file = fopen(($fileName.".csv"),'a+');

     foreach ($data as $row => $value) {
       
       $preserved = array_reverse($value, true);
       $rowData = implode(";", $preserved);

      fwrite($file, $rowData);
       fwrite($file, "\r\n");
```

Comment: The header tells the _browser_ how the file should be interpreted, but for anything else [eg: after saving the file] you need to make sure that whatever you're using to look at the file is using the correct encoding.

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve] so that everyone can reproduce this without having to guess? Also, please read [ask] and as a new user, take the [tour] as well. As it stands, this could be caused by input data or the way you display or interpret the output, but guessing is not a good base for a question here.